# Install errors with RAD 9.6 "No installation adapter registered for type: ant"

Tags: ibm-rad

I am getting the following install error when installing RAD 9.6. What does the message "No installation adapter registered for type: ant" mean? I installed Apache Ant 1.10.1 and then retried the RAD install, but the ANT made no difference.

Additionally I get a similar error with 9.5 and 9.0 too. I am using IBM Installation Manager 1.8.5 32-bit on MS-Windows 10 64-bit. 
[image: error screen shot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was told by the IT folks at my employer that they had encountered this error before. According to them this issue generally appear when your MS-Windows user profile is migrated from MS-Windows OS install to another; like when the OS re-imaged or laptop upgraded. The way they fixed it back then was to uninstall and reinstall the IBM Installation Manager. Once I did that, the install of RAD 9.6 went smoothly without any issues.